# List view permission error in Lightning component

Tags: lightning, lightninglistview

Component:-

```
<aura:component controller="Opportunity_record_apex" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global">
     <aura:handler name="init" value="this" action="{!c.doinit}"/> 
    <aura:attribute name="listopp" type="opportunity__c[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="value" type="List" />
      <div class="slds-page-header">
          <p class="slds-page-header__title slds-truncate" title="Opportunity Table">Opportunity Table</p><br/><br/>
   </div>               

        <lightning:listView aura:id="listViewOpportunity"
                            objectApiName="opportunity__c"
                            listName="listopp"  
                            rows="10"
                            showActionBar="true"
                            enableInlineEdit="true"
                            showRowLevelActions="true"/>   
        </aura:component>
```

JS Controller:-

```
({
    doinit : function(component, event, helper) {

        var action=component.get("c.opplist");
        action.setCallback(this,function(response){
            var state=response.getState();
            if(state=="SUCCESS"){
                component.set("v.listopp",response.getReturnValue());
            }
        });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },

    handleChange: function (component, event) {
        alert(event.getParam('value'));
    }
})
```

Apex controller:-

```
public class Opportunity_record_apex {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static list<Opportunity> opplist(){
        return [select id,Name,Account.Name,Amount, CloseDate , StageName from Opportunity];
    }

}
```

[image: This is the output i am getting]

Answer (score 0):

It's a Permission issue. You need to have read or write Permission to that list view.

> A lightning:listView component represents a list view of records that you own or have read or write access to, and records shared with you. They also include records owned by or shared with users in roles below you in the role hierarchy. You can see only the fields that are visible according to your page layout and field-level security settings.